# Async Messaging Gateway in Spring Integration with RxNetty

Tags: spring-integration, rx-netty

I am trying to combine a Async Messaging Gateway in Spring Integration with RxNetty(Async HTTP). Basically what i want is return an observable/CompletableFuture to the calling thread and use the Observable's zip/map/flatmap for bunch of outbound HTTP Calls in the calling thread. I am just trying to see if that's quite possible. Also if rather than using Rxjava constructs i am better off using aggregator eip to build a simple workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version `4.1` the gateway can return Reactor 2.0 `Promise<?>`:

```
@MessagingGateway
public static interface TestGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "promiseChannel")
    Promise<Integer> multiply(Integer value);

}

    ...

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "promiseChannel")
public Integer multiply(Integer value) {
        return value * 2;
}

    ...

Streams.defer(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
            .get()
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .mapMany(integer -> testGateway.multiply(integer))
            .collect()
            .consume(integers -> ...)
            .flush();
```

Starting with version `5.0` that has been changed to Reactor 3.1 `Mono`.

I'm pretty sure that there are some adapters to convert this types to something valuable for RxJava.

The `CompletableFuture<?>` is also supported on gateway since version `4.2`:

```
CompletableFuture<String> process(String data);

...

CompletableFuture result = process("foo")
    .thenApply(t -> t.toUpperCase());

...

String out = result.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-gateway